# java jar file's multiple entry required from command prompt

Tags: jar, executable

I have a Jar file with three classes P,Q,R all three contain static main function ...
I want to have multiple entries to the Jar file while running from command prompt

jar file name for eg: Main_classes.jar and in the Manifest file Main-Class set is class "P"

command i tried

java -cp Main_Classes.jar Q

gives me no class found exception...

Comment: What OS, is the jar in the same directory as you execute the java command from?  Is the class not found refer to one of your classes?

Comment: That should have worked. Please post full stack trace.

Comment: Are the classes all in the root package?

Comment: OS is windows..all 3classes are under package "P1"....tried with java -cp Main_Classes.jar P1.Q  ...it worked !!

Answer (score 0):

Solution as below .

Contents of manifest file assuming all three files are under package myPackage :

```
   Main-Class: myPackage.P
```

The jar file generation

```
       javac -d . P.java Q.java R.java

       jar -cvfm my.jar manifest.txt myPackage/*.class
```

To run the jar which has its own defined main-class as in manifest file

```
       java -jar my.jar // Executes Class P
```

To run the jar with any of class Q or class R which have main as well

```
       java -cp my.jar myPackage.Q  //Executes class Q
       java -cp my.jar myPackage.R  //Executes class R
       java -cp my.jar myPackage.P  //Executes class P
```